# aws s3: how to get LastModified for object version?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

Given an object (with versions enabled), I am trying to figure out how to fetch the `LastModified` date for all the object's versions.

I found an API that returns versions for a bucket (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html):

```
GET /?versions HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: date
Authorization: signatureValue
```

this API returns the `LastModified` date that I need, but:

1. I do not know how to call this API from my Ruby code using the official aws-sdk gem
2. getting all versions for all objects in a bucket is expensive and I want to get versions with their associated `LastModified` dates just for a single object

I am new to S3 API and the gem, would someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RestBucketGETVersion (aka "version aware list") accepts a prefix parameter that limits results to only that prefix.  If you have an object "foo.txt" that you want to enumerate, you can use that as the prefix.  Just be careful, because this will also match other files like "foo.txt.bak".  But if you're smart about it, you can stop paging through results once you hit a non-match, and it will cost at worst one extra round trip to S3.

Does this series of docs help?

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Bucket.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/BucketVersionCollection.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/PrefixedCollection.html#with_prefix-instance_method